# Circular Geometry

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

A circle of radius $1$ is internally tangent to two circles of radius $2$ at points $A$ and $B$, where $AB$ is a diameter of the smaller circle. What is the area of the region, shaded in the picture, that is outside the smaller circle and inside each of the two larger circles?

[image]

(source: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2004_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_25 )

This is my work can someone please tell me what I did wrong 
Call the center of the circle with radius 1 o. Call the intersection point between the 2 circles c and d. Now let oc equal h. Since ac equals 2 we use pythag and get 
h^2+1=4
so h=sqrt(3)
Now we know that the desired area is the difference of AOC(the ellipse sector) and the quarter circle. Now we do arithmetic and get sqrt(3)pi-pi

Comment: You need to provide a specific drawing for your work (or on top of existing diagram) In general - calculate the intersection between the two large circles and than subtract the small circle. Is this what you tried to do?

Comment: You used the formula for the area of an ellipse, but that is NOT an ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

Label the intersections $C$ and $D$.
Obviously, $\triangle CAB$ and $\triangle DAB$ are equilateral. Meaning sector $BCD$ and $ACD$ has an angle of $120^\circ$. The area of the shaded region plus the area of the circle in the middle is twice the area of the sector less the area of the triangle:
$$\begin{align}
A&=2(A_{\text{sector } ACD}-A_{\triangle ACD})\\
&=2\left(\frac{4\pi}3-\sqrt3\right)
\end{align}$$
Finally, subtract the area of the circle in the middle:
$$A_{\text{shaded}}=\frac{8\pi}3-2\sqrt3-\pi=\frac{5\pi}3-2\sqrt3$$